# How to factor $x^5 - x + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring

As I understand it $x^5 - x + 1$ is not solvable by radicals.   But it splits over $\mathbb{C}$, so how does it factor into linear factors?

Comment: It will factor like $$(x-c_1)(x-c_2)(x-c_3)(x-c_4)(x-c_5)$$ where each $c_i$ is a complex number with no nice closed form.

Comment: $$(x^5 - x + 1) = (x^2 + \alpha x + \beta)(x^2 + \gamma x + \delta) (x + \xi)$$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi < 0$.

Comment: @marvis: Shouldn't $\xi$ be positive?  We know that the polynomial has a root in $(-\infty, 0)$, since $P(-\infty) < 0 < P(0) = 1$, and if this root is $r$ then the polynomial is divisible by $(x-r)$ and so has the form $P'(x)(x+(-r))$ where $-r$ is positive.

Comment: Indeed, $\xi \approx 1.16$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%5Bx%5E5-x%2B1%5D

Comment: @MarkDominus Oh yeah. I wanted to write $\xi > 0$.

Comment: @Marvis You had me worried for a minute.

Answer (score 3):

By Descartes' Rule of Signs, there is one real root. Find it. The result will give you a product of a linear factor times a quartic, which can be solved by radicals. You may also use [Jacobi theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html) to find the roots, since it is in Bring's (reduced) form.

Comment: See Marvis' comment.